# What are the set of options to pass to gcc when compiling C89 code

Tags: c, gcc, c89

I know about `-ansi -pedantic-errors`

Is there any other options to be as defensive as possible, in my code? I mean I don't want to miss any warnings or anything.

Comment: Which version of GCC are you hobbling by insisting on C89?  `-Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror` could be a good starting point (but some versions of GCC may not like `-Wold-style-definition`, or possibly others of those options).  But why are you hobbling your code to the archaic standard?  It's past its retirement age — it's 28 years old this year.

Comment: [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options) are probably helpful too

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: We had this with the previous question of the poster. He insists on using an outdated version of the C language.

Comment: As I tried to make clear already: Using C89/90 makes your code inheritently less safe, because C90 has a lot of legacies and flaws C99 and C11 at least require warnings.

Comment: @it's version 6.3.0

Comment: @JonathanLeffler using C89 mode would be appropriate for rebuilding a codebase written to C89 conformance

Comment: @M.M: but that then begs the question "how much of the standard was actually followed".  If the answer is "don't know", then `-std=c90 -pedantic` is probably as far as you want to go.  If you know the code was written to a stricter set of rules, then you add the extra options.  But 'defensive as possible' implies that they're interesting in being strict and willing to modify code as they go, in which case what I suggest is along the correct lines.  It's hard to give a better answer.  It seems it is not this OP's first assault on the issue.  It appears he is not necessarily learning.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler although C89 is outdated, it's still a well-defined standard. Conforming to it has its uses for compatibility with old or exotic compilers. E.g. you can be sure `msvc` compiles C89 code correctly. I'd say it's good to hint that the uses are very limited and that the OP would probably better just use C11, but there might be reasons not to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to miss any warnings or anything then, just use `-std=` switch. Use `-std=c89. Link [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options) provided by [GNU](https://gcc.gnu.org) is having the information about different switch available. If you are using any other compiler then see the respective documents.